# Iterate over different formControls of formGroup object in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an Angular (4) application that generates a formGroup object in my application component. I want to dynamically add all these components in my template, it expected the following to work.

```
<form [formGroup]="updateValuesForm">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let control of updateValuesForm.controls">
      <input formControlName='control.name' type="text"/>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

But that generates the following error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type
>   'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Is it even possible to achieve this in Angular?

Comment: You can use keys pipe to achieve that https://plnkr.co/edit/U0p2IuTGgCIXh4SKHAaK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, that helped a lot. That solution is hard to find for some reason.